# UI Testing with React/Mocha/Chai - How to test width of element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chai

I'm learning how to do some testing on a UI component in react. I've run into an issues - I have a scenario where, to start, an `<input>` field has a width of 0px. User clicks a button, and the width animates to 200px. User clicks a button again and the `<input>` contracts to 0px again.

The issue I'm running into (using [Chai Jquery](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-jquery/)) is that when selecting .width() of a component it is always returning 0px. Some googling indicates that this happens in Jquery because the DOM hasn't loaded yet. Is there a way to call componentDidMount() in the test, and make the assertion after that?

edit this is the function I'm using to render components (from a tutorial):

```
function renderComponent(ComponentClass, props = {}, state = {}) {
  const componentInstance =  TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers, state)}>
      <ComponentClass {...props} />
    </Provider>
  );

  return $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(componentInstance));
}
```

It's called by passing the React component into the `ComponentClass` field. An example test I am using:

```
  // other imports
  import Navbar from '../../src/containers/navbar';

  let component;

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = renderComponent(Navbar);
  });

  it('has the class nav-bar', () => {
    expect(component).to.have.class('nav-bar');
  });
```

And the kind of test I am trying to run:

```
it('has an initial width of 0px', () => {
  // this is always true
  expect(component.find('input').width()).to.equal(0);
});
```

Comment: Are you using the React TestUtils to render your component on the page?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post with some example tests to try and demonstrate better.